# Can anyone help me find this IC SZ9KH?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, integrated-circuit, components, datasheet

I tried looking for datasheet for SZ9KH but can't find anything. I encountered this IC on a board that needed to be amplified.
Mostly i want to know how does the amplification works? Is it an op-amp or transistor or ...?

This is the whole board. I was told that it was a gas flow-meter circuit.

[image]

The SZ9KH is on the left of the following picture.

[image]

And the schematic, I've drawn from the PCB.

[image]

For SZ9KH:
This signal is on pin 1 and pin 2 in Ground.
[image]

This is on pin 3.
[image]

This goes to pin 4.
[image]

This is on pin 5.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You'd have better chances of someone finding it if you posted more info, e.g. an actual picture of the component, surrounding circuitry, what product the pcb is in etc...

Comment: What capsule? What does it do?

Comment: I edited the question.